# How to save a knn model?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-nn

I need to save the results of a fit of the SKlearn NearestNeighbors model:

```
knn = NearestNeighbors(10)
knn.fit(my_data)
```

How do you save to disk the traied `knn` using Python?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import pickle 

knn = NearestNeighbors(10)
knn.fit(my_data)

# Its important to use binary mode 
knnPickle = open('knnpickle_file', 'wb') 
      
# source, destination 
pickle.dump(knn, knnPickle)  

# close the file
knnPickle.close()
                
      
# load the model from disk
loaded_model = pickle.load(open('knnpickle_file', 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.predict(X_test)
```

refer: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/saving-a-machine-learning-model/

Comment: do not forget to close the pickle file knnPickle.close()

Comment: Thanks for reminding. Edited the code

Answer (score 3):

Importing the library

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
```

Saving your model after fitting the parameters

```
clf.fit(X_train,Y_train)
joblib.dump(clf, 'scoreregression.pkl')
```

Loading my model into the memory ( Web Service )

```
modelscorev2 = joblib.load('scoreregression.pkl' , mmap_mode ='r')
```

Using the loaded object

```
prediction = modelscorev2.predict_proba(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pickle is the standard way of serializing objects in Python.

You can use the pickle operation to serialize your machine learning algorithms and save the serialized format to a file.

Later you can load this file to deserialize your model and use it to make new predictions.

Try this it works!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to
https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/

```
model = knn() # put yours model
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# save the model to disk
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))


# load the model from disk
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.score(X_test, Y_test)
print(result)
```